# Google Chrome Developer Tools are showing the wrong position for highlighted block

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have this problem for a while already and I was hoping it will be fixed with Google Chrome updates, but unfortunately that approach didn't work, so I thought maybe I'll find some help here.

I have encountered a strange behaviour of the Google Chrome. It highlights the blocks, display the autosuggestions and even clicks on the different point of the page than it should.

- It's not a layout problem as the problem exists on any website.
- The problem is happening only when Developer Tools are open and responsive mode is on.
- It is also not an issue with extensions as I've been trying to disable/delete all of them and problem was still existing.
- I've been trying to replicate the issue in Chromium, but wasn't able to.

I'll be happy to hear any suggestions on how to fix that, but I also want to know if I am the only one having such issue.

Check the attached links to pictures, it will give you a better idea of the problem.

[Highlighted block displayed incorrectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5FXj.png)

[Autocomplete suggestions are in the wrong position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REfsq.png)

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome.  Please Edit your Question to include your recent comments, and also note if the issue is happening on another computer with a fresh clean Chrome install.  Then please Delete your comments, so that it's easier to read.

Comment: Thank you for help @ChristopherHostage, I will try to replicate the issue on other machine later today.

Comment: Eventually it was fixed with the latest Chrome release.